# Merge Sort with Java, confusing behaviours in the merge step

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

While I was trying the *merge sort* algorithm with Java, there are yet unclear behaviors occurring in the process.

- The algorithm works fine, no issue, I'm here to get some clarifications about the algorithm that is not behaving up to my expectations.
- This is the same merge sort algorithm, the only difference is I'm using Java's "BigInteger" type for my specific problem solution. So the algorithm is sorting based on the type `BigInteger` therefore some small extra steps are there...

First let's check the code I've written.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MergeSorter {
    public BigInteger[] Merge_Sort(BigInteger[] Arr, int start,  int end){
        if(start<end){
            int mid = (start+end)/2;
            Merge_Sort(Arr, start, mid);
            Merge_Sort(Arr, mid+1, end);
            Merge(Arr, start,mid, end);
        }
        return Arr;
    }

    public void Merge(BigInteger[] Arr, int start, int mid, int end){
        int n1 = mid - start+1;
        int n2 = end - mid;

        BigInteger[] left = new BigInteger[n1+1];
        BigInteger[] right = new BigInteger[n2+1];

        for(int i=0; i<n1; i++){
            left[i] = Arr[start+i-1];
        }

        for(int j=0; j<n2; j++){
            right[j] = Arr[mid+j];
        }

        left[n1] =  null;
        right[n2] = null;

        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        for(int k=start-1;k<end; k++ ){
            if(left[i]!=null && right[j]!=null){
                if((left[i].compareTo(right[j])==-1)
                        ||(left[i].compareTo(right[j])==0)){
                    Arr[k] = left[i];
                    i++;
                }else{
                    Arr[k] = right[j];
                    j++;
                }
            }else if(right[j]!=null){
                Arr[k] = right[j];
                j++;
            }else if(left[i]!=null){
                Arr[k] = left[i];
                i++;
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**What is boiling my brain? (How and what is the problem)**

At the merge step, `Merge(Arr, start, mid, end);` we are using the recursion to run with `start`, `mid` and `end` variable values, however, there's something like "magical" happening in here, that is,
**HOW IS THE ARRAY GETTING SORTED WITHOUT EVEN RETURNING, OR AM I MISSING SOME MORE KNOWLEDGE ABOUT RECURSION?...**

That is where I'm stuck...

I tried some naive method to expose the behavior as well as below:

```
public void printer(int inc, int start, int mid, int end){
    inc++;
    System.out.println("inc: "+inc);
    System.out.println("Merge Step Runs with: "+"Start: "+start+" mid: "+mid+" end: "+end);
}

public void Merge_Sort(int inc, int start,  int end){
    if(start<end){
        int mid = (start+end)/2;
        Merge_Sort( inc, start, mid);
        Merge_Sort( inc, mid+1, end);

        printer( inc,start, mid, end);
    }
}
```

Things doesn't add up, `inc` does not get replaced as the array in merge sort does.

Would love to hear from you for further references for a good read if there's any in relevance to this context.

Comment: Please work out the memory required by this procedure in terms of N=`end - start`; add your reasoning to the question if you want it discussed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is the array getting sorted without even returning

The parameter `Arr` is a *reference* to an array, so when `Merge()` writes to Arr (`Arr[...] = ...`), it updates the original array. The parameter `inc` is a *primitive*, so it is passed by value (a copy of it is made).

You might want to consider changing the merge sort to do less copying. A top down merge sort can be implemented with a one time copy of the entire array, or a bottom up merge sort can be implemented without any copying, just a second working array.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort